# Apache2 not working with PHP

Tags: php, debian, apache-2.4, apache2, php7

I have Apache2 running on a Debian 11 box (x64). It was installed with an Openmediavault ISO, with nginx and PHP 7.4 installed already (for the web UI) I try to install the PHP connector for apache2 (libapache2-mod-php7.4), and it installs fine, but the web server still returns blank PHP code.

I go to get a simple phpInfo, and it returns

```
<?php
phpInfo();
```

The PHP module does not even seem to be loaded into the mods-available folder.

```
root@web1:/etc/apache2/mods-available# ls
access_compat.load  authn_core.load       authz_host.load     cern_meta.load     deflate.conf     filter.load        lbmethod_bybusyness.load  mime.conf         negotiation.load     proxy_hcheck.load    remoteip.load        setenvif.load          status.load
actions.conf        authn_dbd.load        authz_owner.load    cgid.conf          deflate.load     headers.load       lbmethod_byrequests.load  mime.load         proxy_ajp.load       proxy_html.conf      reqtimeout.conf      slotmem_plain.load     substitute.load
actions.load        authn_dbm.load        authz_user.load     cgid.load          dialup.load      heartbeat.load     lbmethod_bytraffic.load   mime_magic.conf   proxy_balancer.conf  proxy_html.load      reqtimeout.load      slotmem_shm.load       suexec.load
alias.conf          authn_file.load       autoindex.conf      cgi.load           dir.conf         heartmonitor.load  lbmethod_heartbeat.load   mime_magic.load   proxy_balancer.load  proxy_http2.load     request.load         socache_dbm.load       unique_id.load
alias.load          authn_socache.load    autoindex.load      charset_lite.load  dir.load         http2.conf         ldap.conf                 mpm_event.conf    proxy.conf           proxy_http.load      rewrite.load         socache_memcache.load  userdir.conf
allowmethods.load   authnz_fcgi.load      brotli.load         data.load          dump_io.load     http2.load         ldap.load                 mpm_event.load    proxy_connect.load   proxy.load           sed.load             socache_redis.load     userdir.load
asis.load           authnz_ldap.load      buffer.load         dav_fs.conf        echo.load        ident.load         log_debug.load            mpm_prefork.conf  proxy_express.load   proxy_scgi.load      session_cookie.load  socache_shmcb.load     usertrack.load
auth_basic.load     authz_core.load       cache_disk.conf     dav_fs.load        env.load         imagemap.load      log_forensic.load         mpm_prefork.load  proxy_fcgi.load      proxy_uwsgi.load     session_crypto.load  speling.load           vhost_alias.load
auth_digest.load    authz_dbd.load        cache_disk.load     dav.load           expires.load     include.load       lua.load                  mpm_worker.conf   proxy_fdpass.load    proxy_wstunnel.load  session_dbd.load     ssl.conf               xml2enc.load
auth_form.load      authz_dbm.load        cache.load          dav_lock.load      ext_filter.load  info.conf          macro.load                mpm_worker.load   proxy_ftp.conf       ratelimit.load       session.load         ssl.load
authn_anon.load     authz_groupfile.load  cache_socache.load  dbd.load           file_cache.load  info.load          md.load                   negotiation.conf  proxy_ftp.load       reflector.load       setenvif.conf        status.conf
```

*Yes, I am aware it is not best practice to run as root*

Extra info:
I got the site from another machine (Win10), as the server is headless.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  Where was the php module installed?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don't know what you mean by where was it installed? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you mean directory, it was at the root directory.

Comment: The php module was installed in the root directory?

Comment: I ran the apt command in the root directory.

Comment: could it be, that you are an end user and try to ask on a business platform? running ls as root is not mostly insecure?

Comment: I am confused what you mean.